# How to set a desired layout for an animating fragment?

Tags: android, animation, layout, fragment

I have a fragment which is animating from right to left. I want to set it to  stop at like 100 units from the left part of the screen. This is what i did so far.

```
    RelativeLayout tempLi;
    Display display = MyActivity.context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int width = display.getWidth();

   tempLi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width-100, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

This line of code is getting the layout 100 units short from the right side. I tried doing `-width + 100` , it didn't work.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Have you tried assigning a left-margin for the layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the left-margin to the layout as follows:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
    tempLi.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: I got an error, `setMargins()` is undefined for `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: Code updated to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Please check.

Comment: Dude, nothing happened. It is covering the entire screen.